# Add Numbers in ReactJS without button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, next.js, addition

Seems like an easy task to add few number but I am not getting any
luck without usage of explicit button to add numbers.

```
  // Defining useState

  const [ totalCount, setTotalCount ] = useState(0)

  // User Can change count of fruits by increment or decrement operator

  const addNum = (apples,mango,orange) => {
    setTotalCount(parseInt(apples) + parseInt(mango) + parseInt(orange))
  }

  console.log("Total Number of Fruits", totalCount)
```

Desired Answer : **Some number between 0 and 3**

Answer getting : **NaN**

Comment: You have to show how you call `addNum`. Also, my guess is that if apples, mango, and orange are state (because user can change the count of fruits by an operator), then `totalCount` is not actually state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component will track the quantities of individual items. The *sum* of the items is **derived state** and should NOT be saved as state of its own. Instead compute the sum on-the-fly -

```js
function App({ items = [] }) {
  const [counts, setCounts] = React.useState(new Map)
  const update = (key, amount) => event =>
    setCounts(m => new Map(m).set(key, (m.get(key) || 0) + amount))
  return <div>
    {items.map(item =>
      <Item key={item} item={item} count={counts.get(item) || 0} update={update} />
    )}
    total: {[...counts.values()].reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)}
  </div>
}

function Item({ item, update, count }) {
  return <div>
    <button type="button" onClick={update(item, -1)} children="➖" />
    {item}: {count}
    <button type="button" onClick={update(item, 1)} children="➕" />
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<App items={["", "", ""]}/>, document.body)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Decomposition of a generic `update` and `sum` function allow you to keep the component logic simplified and allow these functions to be reused in other areas of your program -

```js
function updateCount(map, key, amount) {
  return new Map(map).set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + amount)
}

function sum(iter) {
  return [...iter].reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0)
}
```

```js
function App({ items = [] }) {
  const [counts, setCounts] = React.useState(new Map)
  const update = React.useCallback((key, amount) => event =>
    setCounts(m => updateCount(m, key, amount)),
    []
  )
  return <div>
    {items.map(item =>
      <Item key={item} item={item} count={counts.get(item) || 0} update={update} />
    )}
    total: {sum(count.values())}
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mulan. Does it matter to use "documentByID" as search for these strings and convert to those in numbers and then add.

Comment: @LonelySoul it would be against the react pattern to use `document.getElementById`. instead use a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).